# java.NullPointerException while running this code

Tags: android, jsoup

I have a problem when this Thread is running so my app crashes. I don't really understand, where the problem is.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    //Searching with post request           
    BugSenseHandler.sendEvent("Search started");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
      try {
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("find", etMedName.getText().toString()));

       String prec = "";
       if (cbPrecise.isChecked()) prec = "on";
       else prec = "off";

       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("exact_match", prec));

       HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://mashkovsky.ru/tiki-listpages.php");
       post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       HttpResponse resp = client.execute(post);

       String html = "";
       html = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

       Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "http://mashkovsky.ru/tiki-listpages.php");
       Element content = doc.getElementById("wrapper");
       wView.loadData(content.outerHtml(), "text/html", "utf-8");
       MainActivity.this.removeDialog(SEARCH_DIALOG);   
     }
     catch (ClientProtocolException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
     catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
}).start();             
}
```

I have no stacktrace in LogCat window in eclipse, but [BugSense](http://bugsense.com) shows this short stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ru.pathdevel.mashkovsyreference.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:106)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**UPD: Problem is solved. Everything was in initialization. I was trying to take the main.xml layout widgets, not the searchdialog.xml**

Comment: Where is `cbPrecise` declared?

Comment: It's declared global and initialized in `onCreateDialog`

Comment: This one `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("find", etMedName.getText().toString()));`

Comment: `etMedName` is also declared global and initialized in `onCreateDialog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a breakpoint in the run method of your Runnable, debug the app, check the values of your variables. One seems to be null.

I'd especially concentrate on:

- etMedName
- cbPrecise

Moreover, have you checked whether your HttpResponse contains content?

By the way, removeDialog is deprecated since API level 13. I'd suggest using DialogFragment from the support library instead.

Answer (score 0):

`etMedName` is null or `etMedName.getText()` is null. So you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    if(etMedName==null || etMedName.getText()==null) return;
    ...
}
```